# How would I replace the key options inside an object with a spread inside of a map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which is changing the value of the options key in the inputType multipleChoice object the main object is called cards and I need to set the state to the newTasksIdsArray

I want the multipleChoice.options to have the newArray values so I can setthe state to them

Update: more info

I guess what I am trying to say is I need the a variable to setlocalstroage eventually to be the entireObject with the optiosn array replaced with whatever would be in newTasksIdsArray which i have generated, just not included because It't probably not neccesary

Thanks!

I need my final result to be

```
[
   {
      "inputType":"multipleChoice",
      "uniId":"bzR7bpwzjMxcBEdSF",
      "label":"Preferred Method of Contact",
      "value":"2813348004",
      "multipleChoice":{
         "options":NEW ARRAY GOES HERE
      }
   },
   ...
   KEEP REST OF OBJECT
]
```

```
let test = [];

    cards.map((card) => {
      if (card.inputType === "multipleChoice") {
        //console.log(card);
        card.multipleChoice.options = newTasksIdsArray;
        test.push(...cards);
      }
    });

    console.log(test);

    setCards(test)

    //update localstorage with test as well
```

This is the cards object

```
[
   {
      "inputType":"multipleChoice",
      "uniId":"bzR7bpwzjMxcBEdSF",
      "label":"Preferred Method of Contact",
      "value":"2813348004",
      "multipleChoice":{
         "options":[
            {
               "uniId":"gJ8N6sAJrZZvCcPkp",
               "label":"Cell Phone",
               "checked":false
            },
            {
               "uniId":"Ha9rmssmRkGzpRTn7",
               "label":"Email",
               "checked":true
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "inputType":"shortText",
      "uniId":"AkvioWe6D2ahgDCbW",
      "label":"First Name:",
      "value":"Kanye",
      "multipleChoice":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "inputType":"phoneNumber",
      "uniId":"xwbBBnT2D69QJHHuL",
      "label":"Cell Phone Number",
      "value":"2813348004",
      "multipleChoice":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "inputType":"email",
      "uniId":"62fDs7JtTF4MxMvww",
      "label":"Work Email",
      "value":"kanye@usa.gov",
      "multipleChoice":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "inputType":"address",
      "uniId":"pKAwHmRJKCcKMz8LN",
      "label":"Home Address",
      "value":"123 White House Avenue",
      "multipleChoice":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "inputType":"dropDown",
      "uniId":"K3o689k8G2ZrWEfQc",
      "label":"How did you find us?",
      "value":"2813348004",
      "dropDown":{
         "uniId":"3r9gzPXXjidq9p4fw",
         "options":[
            {
               "uniId":"7hGYT4jv89WxFveaj",
               "label":"Google"
            },
            {
               "uniId":"J2K2W6P4BR7ZEGEao",
               "label":"Referral"
            }
         ]
      },
      "multipleChoice":{
         
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: so you just want a react component to display and edit cards?

Comment: I have the component already I need to manipulate the object cards, with the newArray Values. If you look at the object I need to know how to replace multipleChoice.options with a new array and then take that whole new object and put it in a new variable. Nothing really react specific I need done, I can handle that part

Comment: Do you want just to have a new object with updated keys and values?

Comment: yeah a new object with update key values only for the multipleChoice.options section which takes a new array, everything else stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the cards state was already updated by the reaasignment of the value in the map function so this just works fine to store to localstorage

```
cards.map((card) => {
      if (card.inputType === "multipleChoice") {
        card.multipleChoice.options = newTasksIdsArray;
      }
    });

    window.localStorage.setItem("inputs", JSON.stringify(cards)
```